# How can I use the results of one command to invoke another command multiple times?

Tags: shell

I'd like to pipe the multi-line results of command A into command B, invoking command B once for each line of the output of command A. Like xargs but with multiple invocations.

Comment: You can tell `xargs` to do one command execution per 'word'.  It splits lines into words and treats each word as a potential argument.  If that won't work (blanks in your lines), you use a shell loop: `... | while read line; do commandB "$line"; done` -- or write your own code (I called mine `xargl`, for 'xargs on lines').

Comment: thnaks! why is this a comment? also, how do i do this: "You can tell xargs to do one command execution per 'word'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run command B for each line in the output of command A, use `xargs` with these options:

```
A |  xargs -n1 -d'\n' B
```

Explanation:

- `-d'\n'` tells `xargs` to treat its input one line at a time, rather than the default behavior of dividing the input based on whitespace.
- `-n1` tells `xargs` to run `B` once for each line of input as a single argument.

Comment: great -- i also had to strip whitespace. here's my final command `git branch |grep -v master | tr -d " " | /opt/local/libexec/gnubin/xargs -n1 -d'\n' git branch -d`

Comment: (OS X xargs doesn't have the `-d` feature, so I installed xargs from macports)